# View a message as it works through a BizTalk orchestration?

Tags: sql, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I am trying to find out where a value is getting dropped by BizTalk 2006 R2 as it progresses through my orchestration.  I have been using the Health and Testing utility and can see the Message IDs as they move through, but have a hard time figuring out how to look them up to see their values?

I tried going into SQL and executing the ReadMessage proc, but that returned empty values.

Any Ideas how to find a specific message?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [Orchestration debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa953746%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) tool and put a break point in the Orchestration, then run your message through and then find that suspended Orcherstration, and debug it.